# Arithmetic Shift Right rather than Logical Shift Right

Tags: delphi

I am trying to perform an arithmetic shift right in Delphi. I can't get it to work though, it keeps giving incorrect answers.

Here is my code;

```
  lValue := offset;
  asm
    mov cl,32
    sar lValue,cl
  end;
  hgh := lValue and $FFFFFFFF;
```

When `offset` is set to `1024` and the shift right is set to `32`, `hgh` should equal `0`. In my code, `hgh = 1024`.

Comment: If I recall correctly the instruction only supports shifts up to 31 (5-bit displacement value).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - how would I make it do more?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError's comment is absolutely correct: "... all other IA-32 processors (starting with the Intel 286 processor) do mask the shift count to 5 bits, resulting in a maximum count of 31." There is nothing really wrong about intermixing Pascal and BASM, but you have to be very careful with assembler (just as usual).

Comment: How come in C/C++ it works correctly?

Comment: It cannot work "correctly" on IA-32 processors.

Comment: @Free It's the "you just have to be very careful" that's the problem.

Comment: @Jake the x86 instruction set is comprehensively documented by Intel. Did you read this? If not, why not? You'll find your answer there.

Comment: What do you mean when you say C++ "works correctly"? Shifting a 32-bit integer more than 31 bits to the right with the `>>` operator is undefined. Shifting right by using inline assembler will give the same results as your Delphi code because the assembler is the same in either case.

Comment: Your title seems to indicate that you think there's a difference between logical and arithmetic shifts, but in this case, there is none. For non-negative inputs, they behave identically.

Answer (score 0):

You should conditionally shift by 31 bits for numbers greater or equal to 32